# Unix command to read and cut particular pattern

Tags: grep

I have a file containing the lines below. I want to read the file and extract only `/POC/DEV/STRING/MATCH`.
Which `grep` command should I use to get particular match.

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512M; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512M; support was removed in 8.0

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/app/cloudera-var/CDH-Parcels/parcels/CDH-5.13.3-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.2/jars/hive-common-1.1.0-cdh5.13.3.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
OK
  'hdfs://names/POC/DEV/STRING/MATCH'
Time taken: 5.769 seconds, Fetched: 35 row(s)
```

Comment: So there is some input, and from all the lines, you want to get a line starting with `hdfs://names/` and extract the part between `/` and `'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you are in Linux or macOS this could work:

```
pcregrep -o "hdfs://names\K.+?(?=\')" file
```

The `\K` can be read as excluding everything to the left before it and return only the right part `.+`, and then the `?(?=\')` match any characters until `'` is found.

If in Linux you could try:

```
grep -oP "hdfs://names\K.+?(?=\')" file
```

Comment: Lookarounds with one character kind of make no sense, just `\K[^']*` would be simpler instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with [less command](https://www.sanfoundry.com/4-practical-less-command-examples-and-tips-effective-navigation-in-linux/)?

```
less -p "pattern" <filename>
```

Comment: 'hdfs://names/POC/DEV/STRING/MATCH' is not going to same every time .
basically i wanted to extract start from /POC till last before '  .

Comment: If you can recognize those lines from '/POC' you can use this string as pattern, it should work... what you think about?

Answer (score 0):

- If you want the line contains your pattern:

`grep "/POC/DEV/STRING/MATCH" file`

The output will be: `'hdfs://names/POC/DEV/STRING/MATCH'`

- If you want the exact pattern without the whole line you can add `-o` option to the command:

`grep -o "/POC/DEV/STRING/MATCH"`

The output will be: `/POC/DEV/STRING/MATCH`

Answer (score 0):

A `gnu awk` version

```
awk -F\' 'a=match($0,"hdfs://names") {print substr($2,a+9)}' file
/POC/DEV/STRING/MATCH
```